# Removing the cell borders from header in DataGridView C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zFMA.png)

I am using a DataGridView in C# and I wanted to remove the Cell Border of DataGridView.

```
dataGrid = new DataGridView();
dataGrid.BackgroundColor = Control.DefaultBackColor;
dataGrid.AdvancedColumnHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None; 
dataGrid.AdvancedRowHeadersBorderStyle = DataGridViewAdvancedCellBorderStyle.None;
dataGrid.CellMouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellMouseEventHandler(dataGrid_CellClick);
dataGrid.CellMouseEnter += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGrid_CellMouseEnter);
dataGrid.DataBindingComplete += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventHandler(dataGrid_DataBindingComplete);
dataGrid.CellPainting += new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellPaintingEventHandler(dataGrid_CellPainting);
dataGrid.DataSource = this._lstWorklet;
dataGrid.Columns.Add("Action", "Action");
dataGrid.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1018, 434);
dataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells;
dataGrid.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
dataGrid.CellBorderStyle = DataGridViewCellBorderStyle.SingleHorizontal;
dataGrid.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = dataGrid.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
dataGrid.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionForeColor = dataGrid.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor;
dataGrid.ReadOnly = true;
dataGrid.RowTemplate.Height = 48;
dataGrid.ColumnHeadersHeight = 48;
dataGrid.RowHeadersVisible = false;
dataGrid.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
dataGrid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = new Font(dataGrid.Font, FontStyle.Bold);
dataGrid.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
dataGrid.MultiSelect = false;
```

Comment: [DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewadvancedborderstyle) -- Or paint the headers' content yourself, to generate some custom design. E.g., [Problem while scrolling merged Header Cells of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67246419/7444103)

Comment: @Jimi I have already defined DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle which is not providing me the expected result. -Thanks

Comment: Well, you should post that code then, so it can be fixed.