# Multi-layered Column Header in DataGridView VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I have Datatable which has output like these:

| id | basic_no | currency | sell_price | buy_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1a | 1 | USD | 400 | null |
| 1a | 1 | YEN | 3 | null |
| 2a | 2 | USD | 10 | null |
| 2a | 2 | WON | null | 15 |
| 3a | 3 | WON | 75 | null |

Then I want my DataGridView (using VB.net) shows the output like these:

[image: Multi Layered Column Header]

Kindly need your help, Thank you so much

Comment: [Problem while scrolling merged Header Cells of a DataGridView](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67246419/7444103)